# Alternative to python exec function

Tags: python, loops, expression, exec

I have a simple use case where i need to print expressions and execute them
automatically. I see several posts suggesting to avoid this as there couple be better alternatives. In this case I am unable to decide on alternatives.
Here is the problem.  I have a list of elements and I'm trying to 
 1.iterate over each element 
 2.print an expression 
 3.execute the expression

Here is a psuedocode

```
#Define the dataset

import pandas as pd
df_scr_crd = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY'], 
        'SCR_STRT': [10, 20, 30, 99999, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
        'POINTS': [100, 200, 300, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40]}
df_scr_crd_d = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_crd, columns = ['Subject', 'SCR_STRT', 'POINTS'])

df_scr_cns = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'PSY'], 
        'CNS': ['min', 'max']}
df_scr_cns_d = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_cns, columns = ['Subject', 'CNS'])

df_scr_crd_d

#Define and Iterate over the list

list = ['MATH', 'PSY']
for i in list:
    print "{0}_bin".format(i)
    print "{0}_bin = df_scr_crd_d.loc[df_scr_crd_d.Subject == '{0}', 'POINTS'].tolist()".format(i)
    exec "{0}_bin = df_scr_crd_d.loc[df_scr_crd_d.Subject == '{0}', 'POINTS'].tolist()".format(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use exec, then you can use eval(), which is described as,

```
eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])
```

The arguments are a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string and optional globals and locals. If provided, globals must be a dictionary. If provided, locals can be any mapping object.

Changed in version 2.4: formerly locals was required to be a dictionary.

The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace. If the globals dictionary is present and lacks ‘**builtins**’, the current globals are copied into globals before expression is parsed. This means that expression normally has full access to the standard **builtin** module and restricted environments are propagated. If the locals dictionary is omitted it defaults to the globals dictionary. If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where eval() is called. The return value is the result of the evaluated expression. Syntax errors are reported as exceptions. Example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print eval('x+1')
2
```

This function can also be used to execute arbitrary code objects (such as those created by compile()). In this case pass a code object instead of a string. If the code object has been compiled with 'exec' as the mode argument, eval()‘s return value will be None.

Hints: dynamic execution of statements is supported by the exec statement. Execution of statements from a file is supported by the execfile() function. The globals() and locals() functions returns the current global and local dictionary, respectively, which may be useful to pass around for use by eval() or execfile().

See ast.literal_eval() for a function that can safely evaluate strings with expressions containing only literals.
For More information on eval visit - [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: Is it safer to use eval instead of exec? In my case I want to create and execute dynamic statements . What are the typical issues in using exec ? I think using global  and locals I can always see what is consumed by the expression in order to resolve. Is that right?